# Most efficient way to group overlapping ranges?

Tags: loops, collections, iteration

I have an in-memory `List<Event>` that could be anything from 1 to 50000+ values long (*not ideal but that is the case*). Each `Event` contains a `openTime` attribute and a `closedTime` attribute that are stored as `Long`.

Given that events can overlap I need to determine the amount of time that **NO** event was active. When you look at it graphically its not very difficult.

[image]

I've implemented several solutions but I'm finding it quite difficult to find a solution that doesn't have a significant time resource impact! My current solutions include;

1. Iterating over the Collection; for every value I determine if any other values in the collection overlap by iterating and finding any in the range.
2. Incrementally looping through every millisecond (around 60000 - ie.1 hour) in the range and seeing if any of the collection elements are active at that time.

Neither of these are performance friendly so any suggestions on an efficient way of achieving this would be very appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Event
{
    int start, end;
}

Use quick sort to sort events as follow:

1. Event x with start time less than event y start time must appear first in array.
2. Event x with start time equals to event y start time and with end time less than y end time must appear first in array.

Then, set inActionEvent to event 0.
iterate over the array of events and for every event i that dont overlap with inActionEvent get the free time between them. every time after checking the overlapping between the inActionEvent and the i event, change the inActionEvent to i event if they do not overlap. and set inActionEvent to i event if they overlap and i end time greater than inActionEvent end time. otherwise keep inActionEvent as it is (inActionEvent could start before i event and ends after i finish, in this case you don't replace inActionEvent with i event).

Complexity:
O(n * lg n) for quick sort and O(n) for the iteration = O(nlgn) and some could say it's O(n)

your first solution takes O(n*n) minimum.

Which mean this one is so fast.

Sample Code:

```
inActionEvent = 0;
// dont forget to get free time form time 0 to start time of first event
for (int i=1;i<numberOfEvents;i++)
{
    if (!overlap(inActionEvent, i))
    {
        getFreeTimeBetweenThem(inActionEvent, i);
        inActionEvent = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (events[inActionEvent].endtime<events[i].endtime)
            inActionEvent = i;
        else
            // do nothin
    }
}
// again dont forget to get free time from last event endtime to the end of day or something.
```

Comment: This is better than my approach and has lead me down some good ideas. I am not entirely convinced it is the most efficient so I'm just going to hold off on marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think that such problems can be solved in less that O(nlgn) and that by definition. You can wait for a bit but you will not find better than nlgn. and it is practical.

Comment: don't you think since this is the best answer you got. and it's really a good one and gave you ideas. that its time to accept it :)